# In shopify hide from text from non logged in customer

Tags: shopify

I have been using:

```
{% if customer %}  
    Add to cart code goes here 
{% endif %}
```

To hide cart buttons from non-customers, But is there a code to hide things from customers? I want to show non-customers a link so sign up, but I don't want customers to see that link once they are logged in.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use if else

```
{% if customer  %}
<a href="/account">Your Account</a>
{% else %}
{{ 'Log in' | customer_login_link }}
{% endif %}
```